# Install packages and libraries in a local directory on server

Tags: unix

I have accession to universities server:  Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 6.2.

My work is to test various scientific analysis programs.

I have no problem untar'ing and running them in my local directory. But most of them have lots of dependencies (perl libraries, RE2, GNU SL, glibc.i686 ) - whenever I try to install those dependencies I come up with the permission problem.

All of those packages require root to install.

Is there a way how can I install various different packages only in my local directory without asking root to install them system wide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but the procedure varies per package. Many modern Unix packages have a `configure` script that you must run, which takes a `--prefix` option + argument specifying where the package should be installed. A directory such as `$HOME/pkg` would be a good options for these. Other configuration/building/installation scripts have similar options.

When building a package with dependencies, make sure you have `$HOME/pkg/bin` in your `PATH`, `$HOME/pkg/lib` in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and pass `-I$HOME/pkg/include` and `-L$HOME/pkg/lib` to the compiler and linker, respectively. E.g., put the following in your shell startup file (`.bashrc` for Bash):

```
PATH=$HOME/pkg/bin:$PATH
CFLAGS=-I$HOME/pkg/include
LDFLAGS=-L$HOME/pkg/lib
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/pkg/lib
```

(You shouldn't have to install glibc, ever.)